# Navigation with headings below each point

Tags: html, css

[image]

The best way to describe what I want to do is using this image. As you can see I have 3 different images as background (which are three different Divs) and I want to insert 3 List Points (here named as: "LV", "RP", "IP") with a centred description/heading below (here as: Lv: 15, RP: 16975 and so on).

My biggest problem is to handle the centred width of those elements. I have no idea how to solve this the best way regarding the CSS.

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="package">
    <div class="item-description">
        <div class="col-md-3"><span class="title">LV</span><span class="description">15</span></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><span class="title">RP<span><span class="description">16975</span></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><span class="title">IP<span><span class="description">40000</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you provide your markup so far? (including css rules)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

It's using quite a few elements (which could possibly be converted into pseudo elements), but it shows a **general overview** of what you might be looking for.

Also, with the id's and classes this shouldn't make it too hard to alter for your needs.

```css
.container {
  width: 32%;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
.container .title {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 32%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
#one {
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/300/300);
}
#two {
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/200/200);
}
#three {
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/300/200);
}
```

```html
<div id="one" class="container">
  <div class="title">200
    <div class="desc">I'm a very long description</div>
  </div>
  <div class="title">300
    <div class="desc">desc</div>
  </div>
  <div class="title">400
    <div class="desc">Be More Dog</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="two" class="container">
  <div class="title">200
    <div class="desc">desc</div>
  </div>
  <div class="title">300
    <div class="desc">I'm a tree.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="title">400
    <div class="desc">What is a description?</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="three" class="container">
  <div class="title">200
    <div class="desc">desc</div>
  </div>
  <div class="title">300
    <div class="desc">a description of what?</div>
  </div>
  <div class="title">400
    <div class="desc">Don't you like, er, trees?</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**this might also work:**

*Note:* I've used a pseudo effect here, but to keep my code 'minimal', rather than applying it to individual items (as you would for individual descriptions), i've just used an existing item.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.sec {
  width: 33%;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/200/200);
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 200px;
  margin-left: -0.5%;
}
.col {
  width: 32%;
  margin-left: -0.5%;
  font-size: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
}

.col:after{
  padding-top:25px;
  font-size: 10px;
  position:absolute;
  content:"description";

  left:25%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="sec">
  <div class="col">
    title
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    title2
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    title3
  </div>
</div>


<div class="sec">
  <div class="col">
    title
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    title2
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    title3
  </div>
</div>


<div class="sec">
  <div class="col">
    title
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    title2
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    title3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome solution and funny cat pics lol. Going to try this now!

Comment: Okay I've tried it but I am struggling with the positioning. Using your exact CSS the browser positions my title + descriptions 100 px (margin-top) below my image. Happens because of my way I've created the three columns I guess, but atm I am to stupid to position it correctly. I created the divs with skeleton (one-third column).

Comment: @kentor: you might need to play with your margining, as i've just presumed your overall height to be 200px (this was a presumption only), so you should look at what i've written, and see which aspect it causing difficulty (i'm afraid i can't help without seeing what's wrong)

Comment: @kentor: looks like a positioning issue. Try adding **position: absolute;** to either (a) your 'title' div (with corresponding top: and left: styles) or (b) a 'wrapper' element (which should group around your title divs)

Answer (score -1):

Try this in your css

```
.description, .title{float:left; width:100%; text-align:center;}
```